# Entity Framework 1:1 Relationship Identity Columns

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I cannot get two separate tables to save with a relationship and two identity columns. I keep getting errors like A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column. Column: 'OlsTerminalId'. I can't imagine that this setup is abnormal.

```
[DataContract]
    public class OlsData {
        private static readonly DateTime theUnixEpoch = new DateTime(1970, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, DateTimeKind.Utc);

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int OlsDataId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "created")]
    [NotMapped]
    public double Created {
        get { return (Timestamp - theUnixEpoch).TotalMilliseconds; }
        set { Timestamp = theUnixEpoch.AddMilliseconds(value); }
    }

    [InverseProperty("OlsData")]
    [DataMember(Name = "terminal")]
    public virtual OlsTerminal OlsTerminal { get; set; }
}

[DataContract]
public class OlsTerminal {
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int OlsTerminalId { get; set; }

    public int OlsDataId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "account")]
    [NotMapped]
    public virtual OlsAccount OlsAccount { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "terminalId")]
    public string TerminalId { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Name = "merchantId")]
    public string MerchantId { get; set; }

    public virtual OlsData OlsData { get; set; }
}

 public class OlsDataContext : DbContext {
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder aModelBuilder) {
            aModelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
        }

        public OlsDataContext(string aConnectionString) : base(aConnectionString) {}
        public DbSet<OlsData> OlsData { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OlsTerminal> OlsTerminal { get; set; }
        public DbSet<OlsAccount> OlsAccount { get; set; }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because 1:1 relationship in EF is always build on Primary keys. So FK in `OlsTerminal` table must by `OlsTerminalId` and FK cannot be autogenerated - it must be value of PK from `OlsData`.

The reason why it must be done this way is requirement for uniqueness of FK value in dependent entity to build real 1:1 instead of 1:N. EF doesn't support unique constraints / candidate keys yet so the only way how to enforce the uniqueness is to use place FK on PK of dependent entity.